# Why am I getting a parseerror when using jQuery's ajax()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, parse-error

Can someone tell me why in the world I keep getting a parseerror in the console with the following code?

```
$.ajax({
    url : "file.php",
    data : data,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function (request) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error : function (request, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I have validated my JSON with jsonlint.com and it's Valid.

The Response Headers being returned in the Net tab of Firebug are:

> Content-Length    19
>
> Keep-Alive    timeout=5, max=96
>
> Connection    Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type  application/json

Comment: What do you see in Firebug's Net tab?

Comment: Is there more detail in the error?

Comment: The code you have posted does not throw any errors, what is the exact error you are getting? Perhaps the name or value of the form input (I'm guessing) contains invalid characters.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `dataType` to `text`?  You should then be able to `console.log` the return data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can send json from PHP

```
$response = array("title" => "One");

echo json_encode($response);
```

If **{ "title": "One" }**  is the response, Content-Length of response should be **18**, but from your description I can see that it is **19**. So something is wrong in the response json string, please check it.

Comment: From the screenshot what I can understand is that response is json but string encoded in json. Usually this happens when we do like this 
`echo json_encode('{ "title": "One" }');`

Either you can set content type as json and use
`echo '{ "title": "One" };`

or make the response object and encode it json and use echo like this 
`$response = array("title" => "One");
   
echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turned out there was an error in my PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that the `name` or `value` of `this` may have invalid characters. Instead of concocting your own `data` string how about letting jQuery do it for you:

```
data  = $this.serialize();
```

Comment: @Zoolander I know you posted code that declared `dataType : 'json'` but I just have to check, you're not setting `dataType : 'jsonp'` are you? Because the response would almost certainly create a parse-error if the `dataType` is not properly set...

Comment: @Zoolander Maybe set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`?

Comment: @Zoolander Hows about: `$.getJSON('file.php', data, function (response) {console.log('success');});`?